# why jasperreport prints always landscape on A4?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have created a jasperreports in almost the same size of A6(width = 595 height = 842)format and i want it be printed on the A4 in portrait and in the middle but it prints always in landscape on A4.
I use ireport 5.5.0 and jasperreport 5.5.0 to create and display it by java.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your report is designed in A6? WHy don't you change the printer settings then?

Comment: It is almost the same size of A6(width = 595 height = 842). this is the reason why I do print it on A4.

Comment: You can look at this post: [Jasper Report. How to print to a file using a specified printer driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19894861/876298)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the orientation of the report, 
You can set it by going to the **Report Inspector** and selecting the report, and navigate to the properties of the report. There in the **Page Size** you can see, a property called **orientation** you can change it from **Portrait to Landscape.**

If you have done this earlier then you can go to the File menu from the Menu Bar in iReport and there is an option called **Page Setup** here you can set the printing specification.

Hope that this helps.
Thanks.

Comment: I have changed Page Setup too but has no effect on the report preview and end printed result because i use java to print the report not the ireport. I use ireport to design the report, and any changes to the page setup in ireport has no effect in my_report.jrxml and my_report.jasper